# Action From Local Notification Opened (iOS)

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, detect

I've searched other questions similar to this here and I can't find any that seem to actually work. What I'm trying to do is when the user opens the app from a local notification, I need it to execute some code (such as opening the UIMessageComposer or displaying a UIAlertView). Anyone have any idea on how I would do this? Just as a note it is a **local** notification **not** a **push** notification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement this method in you **AppDelegate.m** file

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

You can do want you want in this.

Here's a good tutorial on how to work with Local notifications. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];

if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder"
                                                    message:notification.alertBody
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a direct copy of the code in the AppCoda link in the answer by @Ahmed.